# Python "conditionals" in nested for loop

Tags: python

**getcat(di) - (line 6)** function returns either "None" or some string to my main function.

I would like to add this string in dict if it's not None... Here is code:

```
getids = Url.objects.values_list('keyword', 'id', 'url')
    for keyword, id, url in getids:            
        if Url.objects.get(id=id).url != None:
        ...
        ...
        ala = getcat(anResults)
        
        if str(ala) != 'None':
            dictt['shopping'] = ala         
        else:
            pass
```

Problem is that once it passes !='None' it keeps adding that same string to all future loops.

I tried putting break everywhere and can't seem to make it work. If I replace

```
dictt['shopping'] = ala
```

with:

```
print url, ala
```

it works correctly and prints just the right url and ala value.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please consider adding [mcve].

Comment: Off-topic: When comparing to `None`, use `is`/`is not`, not `==`/`!=`. e.g. Test `if Url.objects.get(id=id).url is not None:`. `None` should almost always be tested using the object identity operators, not rich comparison operators, avoiding overhead and (for poorly written rich comparison operators) exceptions being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

This part of the code `str(ala) != 'None'` is comparing a string to another **string** with value **None**.

If you want a explicit comparing you can re-write to `str(ala) != None` *(no quotes over None statement)*

The other way is to re-write a more pythonic way like:

```
if ala:
    dictt['shopping'] = ala
```